# ¿Por que cada vez que uso equals() me sale : "java.lang.NullPointerException"? java poo

Tags: java, poo

Buenas estoy haciendo programas de poo y cada vez que quiero usar el metodo equals() al ejecutar el codigo me salta en rojo : "java.lang.NullPointerException" , por que sera?

```
public class Usuario {

private String usuario;
private String contraseña;

public Usuario(String nombre , String contraseña) {

    this.usuario = nombre ;
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
}

public String getNombre () {

    return this.usuario ;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {

    this.usuario = nombre ;
}


public String getContraseña() {


    return this.contraseña;
}

public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {


    this.contraseña = contraseña;
}
```

}

```
public class Sistema {

private String nombre;
private Usuario listaDeUsuarios[];
int usuariosAgregados = 0;

public Sistema(String nombre, int cantidadDeUsuarios) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.listaDeUsuarios = new Usuario[cantidadDeUsuarios];

}

public String getNombre() {

    return this.nombre;

}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Usuario[] getListaDeAutos(Usuario listaDeUsuarios) {

    return this.listaDeUsuarios;
}

public void setListaDeUsuarios(Usuario[] listaDeUsuarios) {

    this.listaDeUsuarios = listaDeUsuarios;

}

public boolean loguearUsuario(String usuario, String contraseña) {

    boolean estado = false;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < listaDeUsuarios.length; i++) {
        if (listaDeUsuarios[i].getNombre().equals(usuario)
                && listaDeUsuarios[i].getContraseña().equals(contraseña)) {

            estado = true;
        }

        else {

            estado = false;
        }
    }

    return estado;
}

public void agregarUsuarios(Usuario usuario) {

    listaDeUsuarios[usuariosAgregados] = usuario;
    usuariosAgregados++;

}
```

}

Comment: Comparte el código donde tienes es error porque esta como complicado adivinar por que tienes un error de ese tipo...

Comment: Com dice @SGarcia si compartes el main() donde falla será más fácil ayudarte. ¿Cuándo llamas a loguearUsuario le pasas strings con datos?

Comment: Adicional a lo que te han comentado de verificar que estás ejecutando en el main(), es una mala práctica colocar a los nombre de métodos, clases, atributos, variables, etcétera, la letra Ñ. Yo creo que se te ha de estar olvidando agregar el usuario creado o instanciado mediante el método agregarUsuarios(usuario), también te comento que tienes un método llamado getListaDeAutos(), que no sé que tenga que ver con los usuarios.

Comment: Por favor ahora, agrega el `main()` como nombro @EdwinVasquez porque aunque tienes varios errores en lo que se ve, nada refleja donde podría estar el error que dices tener. Por otro lado, también comparte el error copiado de la consola de JAVA, para ver bien que es lo que falla.
También recuerda leer las reglas y recomendaciones de la pagina para hacer preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Quiero darte varios puntos a corregir en tu codigo:

1. Siguiendo las buenas practricas, debes crear metidos que te
   permitan obtener la cantidad de usuarios, así evitar usar el
   `.length()` en tus for. (opcional)
2. El metodo `agregarUsuarios()` Esta recibiendo un objeto de tipo
   Usuario como parametro, cosa que esta mal, debe recibir los datos
   para CREAR el objeto de tipo `Usuario` en el arreglo de USUARIOS
   `listaDeUsuarios[]`, permitiendo así el uso del CONSTRUCTOR de la
   clase Usuario, el cual permite crear objetos del tipo Usuario.
   Correccion:

   ```
   public void agregarUsuarios(String nomUser, String contra) {
       listaDeUsuarios[usuariosAgregados] = new Usuario(nomUser, contra);
       usuariosAgregados++;
   }
   ```
3. De nuevo siguiendo las buenas practicas, elimina los caracteres
   especiales de tu código, en este caso las ñ, evita usarlas en el
   código, solo emplearlas en tus `Strings`.

### Analisis del problema:

En resumen es el siguiente: Estas creando una lista de usuarios con un tamaño definido, el cual cuando la iteres, iteraras sobre todos los espacios, incluso cuando están `null`, de manera que, si solo has agregado 1 usuario a este arreglo, digamos que en la primera iteracion lo encuentra, como no le estas poniendo un `Break;` al `for` del método loguearUsuario(), seguirás iterando, incluso sobre espacios vacios y ahi es donde el error se localiza, estas diciéndole a java que intente usar una función `.equals()` con un `null`, cosa que lanzara la excepción `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

### **Solucion:**

1. Realizar todos los cambios hasta ahora mencionados.
2. El `for` de tu método `loguearUsuario()` tendrá que ir de la
   siguiente manera:  `for (i = 0; i < usuariosAgregados; i++)` ya que
   lo estabas haciendo recorrer todos los espacios, incluyendo los
   vacíos (`null`) y esto es lo que salta tu error. Así que, con la
   corrección previamente nombrada, solo buscaras el nombre y contraseña
   en los campos donde si hay usuarios almacenados.
3. Agrega una sentencia `break;` cuando el nombre y contraseña sea
   encontrado, porque si no lo haces, cuando lo encuentres, seguirá
   iterando, y obviamente solo habrá una coincidencia, así que las
   iteraciones a continuación volverán tu estado a `false`.

Espero haya sido de ayuda, quedo atento.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta sobre código Java ***¿Por qué cuando uso equals() me sale : “java.lang.NullPointerException”?*** almenos, uno de los dos objetos que estas comparando (strings) es nulo.

**java.lang.NullPointerException (NPE)** es frecuente en Java cuando no se controlan ciertas condiciones. En tu caso falla el código:

```
if (listaDeUsuarios[i].getNombre().equals(usuario)
    && listaDeUsuarios[i].getContraseña().equals(contraseña)) {
        estado = true;
}
```

Donde `usuario` y `contraseña` los has pasado al método que lo contiene. Antes del bucle comprueba si ambos strings son válidos, por ejemplo:

```
if (usuario == null || contraseña == null) {
    // Aquí puedes generar un mensaje que te advierta que está 
    // fallando, p.e. un mensaje de log
    return false;
}
```

incluir condiciones de lógica de negocio, por ejemplo que la contraseña tenga almenos 8 caracteres, etc.

```
if (usuario == null || contraseña == null) {
    // Aquí puedes generar un mensaje que te advierta que está 
    // fallando, p.e. un mensaje de log
    return false;
}
if (usuario.equals("") || contraseña.equals("") || contraseña.length < 8) {
    // Aquí puedes generar un mensaje que te advierta que está 
    // fallando, p.e. un mensaje de log
    return false;
}
```

Puedes setear variables locales con los otros valores que vas a comparar dentro del bucle y volver a comprobar si son nulos para evitar la NPE:

```
String user_to_check = listaDeUsuarios[i].getNombre();
String pw_to_check   = listaDeUsuarios[i].getContraseña();

if (user_to_check != null && pw_to_check != null) {
    // Aquí puedes guardar un mensaje de log -> todo OK

    if (user_to_check.equals(usuario) && pw_to_check.equals(contraseña)) {
        estado = true;
    }
} else {
    // Aquí puedes generar un mensaje que te advierta que está 
    // fallando, p.e. un mensaje de log
}
```

***Nota:*** a partir de Java8 también puedes comprobar si tienes valores nulos usando la clase [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) para evitar NPE.

Saludos.